# Visibility hidden does not work on Microsoft Edge with CSS content: url();

Tags: css, visibility, microsoft-edge, hidden

See Fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/8wk0tsnL/8/

The offending part is this (works on FF, Chrome, IE, but not in Edge) :

```
.testclass:after {
  content: url(http://placekitten.com/96/139);
  visibility:hidden;
}

.testclass:hover:after, .testclass:hover:before {
  visibility:visible;
}
```

The image is not hidden in Edge. If you replace the `content: url(...);` with a text string `content: "example";`, it works fine in Edge.

Is this a bug ? Any known workarounds ?

(Edge has less than 5% browser market share, so I do not want to pollute my code with very exotic or sparsely supported solutions).

Comment: Yes, that's a bug. And in fact a regression, given that it used to work in IE!

Comment: @BoltClock Yes indeed, it works in IE. And weird that in Edge, it works with text, but not with an image. I tried to search on the Edge developers' website, but did not immediately find it. I assume, as it is a known bug, that it has been flagged?

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted. I searched on SO and did not find any other references to this bug ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest for you use opacity property once you can use transition to make it smooth, by the way it have a downside using opacity it's hide the element but still with the clickable area.

```
.testclass:after{
   content: url(http://placekitten.com/96/139);
   opacity: 0;
}

.testclass:hover:after{
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: The canius.com reference is besides the point (it concerns the Page Visibility API, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API, hence not so relevant for the CSS property . And thanks for the `opacity` suggestion. I updated the Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/8wk0tsnL/9/), and it visually works, but the hidden content also shows up if you Hover over the hidden element itself (it remains "clickable" as well). Not optimal, but I might implement this for Edge only (using the CSS browser hack for Edge). If you could update your answer with these two points, I can accept.

Comment: Well, so i suggest for you use `display` instead of `opacity` it will remove the clickable area, about the updated my answer i don't got the point, could you explain better or suggest a edit for me ? Thanks !!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I didn't mention that `display` is not appropriate solution because the transition does not work with this (which is important functionality in my case). For the edit : (1) remove the reference to the canius.com website, as this is not relevant for the question (see my previous comment), and (2) you could add that `opacity` has the downside of the clickable area. Thanks.

Comment: Oh i got not about the display none, btw updated the answer, thanks !!